# New record Updating old record automatically in Array

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am trying to store 2 rows in array but the second row is updating the first row already stored.

```
  UserRole: UserRoleDTO;
  UserRoleArray: UserRoleDTO[];     
  rolesstring=["1","2"]      
  this.roleidArray = rolesstring.split(',');
  let UserArrayData = [];
  let count = 0;
  for (let roledata of this.roleidArray) {
    this.UserRole.roleid = +roledata;
    this.UserRole.userid = +UserId;
    this.UserRole.isactive = 1;
    this.UserRole.entryby = 1;
    console.log('RoleId which need to store in UserArrayData :' + this.UserRole.roleid);
    UserArrayData[count] = this.UserRole;
    console.log('Data stored in UserArrayData :' + UserArrayData[count].roleid);
    count = count + 1;
  }
  this.UserRoleArray = UserArrayData;
  console.log('RoleId which is stored in UserArrayData[0]:' + UserArrayData[0].roleid);// here it is always showing the last roleid stored
```

The result for UserArrayData[0].roleid should be as 1 but it is displaying as 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue with deep cloning, As whenever you assigning `UserArrayData[count] = this.UserRole;` it's assigning it's reference. So to over come this you need to assign deep copy to [**Object.assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Try this:

```
 UserArrayData[count] = Object.assign({}, this.UserRole);
```

Or as @JB suggested you can create a local variable inside fol loop.

Try this:

```
  for (let roledata of this.roleidArray) {
    let tmpObj = this.UserRole;
    tmpObj.roleid = +roledata;
    tmpObj.userid = +UserId;
    tmpObj.isactive = 1;
    tmpObj.entryby = 1;
    console.log('RoleId which need to store in UserArrayData :' + tmpObj.roleid);
    UserArrayData[count] = this.UserRole;
    console.log('Data stored in UserArrayData :' + UserArrayData[count].roleid);
    count = count + 1;
  }
```

Comment: Or better: stop using an instance property and use a local variable instead, and create a new object at each iteration instead of reusing the same object and clone it.

Comment: That's not what I meant. What I meant was: remove the instance property UserRole completely, and use `UserArrayData.push({roleid: +roledata, userid: +UserId, ...});`

Comment: Yes that's nice. But the way I did that can also seems to work. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's not about "working" or "not working". It's about being readable, logical, and using the appropriate scope. An instance property is meant to hold the state of the object. A local variable is all you need for this logic. An instance property shouldn't replace a local variable.